# Zepto.js 'tap' not working/causing issues

Tags: jquery, touch, zepto

I'm using Zepto to create a side menu for a mobile app, (same kind used everywhere, moves content over and shows sidebar content).

I've got it working using click events but when I port it over to Zeptos tap event it causes issues, the menu will slide out but immediate jump back in again and not hold its position.

Here's the code along with a fiddle

```
var     sidemenu_width = $('#side-menu').width(),
        hidden = true,
        header = $('header');   

    //header.css('margin-top', -list_height);       
    //$('nav').css('height', nav_height);
    $('#side-menu').css('margin-right', -sidemenu_width);


    $('#menu_toggle').on('tap',function(){
            if(hidden == true){
                $('#side-menu').animate({
                    marginRight: '0'
                }, 400, 'EaseOutQuart')

                hidden = false;
            } else {
                $('#side-menu').animate({
                    marginRight: -sidemenu_width
                }, 400, 'EaseOutQuart')

                hidden = true;
            }
        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uBwna/2/

Cheers!

Comment: `touch.js` in your resources is an HTML file and not a JS file. This is a reason for your fiddle not working.

Comment: I've updated that, it's working in the fiddle but thats because it's a click event (hard to test tap events on a computer) I just included it so people could see how it worked, the menu button to toggle the sidemenu is in the top right hand corner or the nav bar. Without trying it through a mobile device its hard for me to replicate the issue for you guys, sorry!